# How to know the length of the longest row in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with a quality control table, and I want to find (or know) the longest row which contains the lagest number of cells. for example:

```
aa | bb | cc | dd |
aa | kk |
aa | dd | ss |
```

Well, I want the program can tell me the longest row is the first one, which contains 4 columns. I've used this code:

```
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
my_line = Selection.Row
my_column= Selection.Column + 1
```

But it can only give me the length of the last line but not the longest one. So if you've some ideas please leave a comment.

Comment: Can you clarify? I sounds like you want to find the ROW with the most populated cells *aka* the last populated column. Longest line sounds like you are looking at the content within the cells and not the cells themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) with a wildcard. Start at A1 and look backwards (i.e. xlPrevious). The Find will quickly find the last used cell by column.

```
Dim lst As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet7")
    Set lst = .Cells.Find(What:=Chr(42), After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
End With
Debug.Print lst.Row
Debug.Print lst.Column
```